# jQuery Range slider grep return items with min and max

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I have the following data:

```
unit 251
path "M256.57 475.46L251.00 4...49 471.59L259.64 472.92"
name "unit 251"
status "Sold"
color "#f50000"
size "3200"
price "3000000"
```

this small piece comes from a big JSON Array, I am using jQuery ui rangeslider and i am trying to use [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to return the items by the price that fall into the min and max of the range slider.

Here is my code so far:

```
//////////Filter Range Slider

    function filterUnitPrice(minVal,maxVal){
        var obj = json['properties'];
        return jQuery.grep(Object.keys(obj), function(item){
            return obj[item].price < maxVal;
        });
    }

    jQuery('div#price-range')[0].slide = null;
    jQuery( "#price-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 350000,
        values: [ 0, 300000 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            var minVal = ui.values[0];
            var maxVal = ui.values[1];
            var result = filterUnitPrice(minVal,maxVal);
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
//////////Filter Range Slider
```

i am not quiet sure what i am doing incorrectly but it always seems to return `[]`...

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that your `grep` function return the element and not its key try changing the function into:

```
function filterUnitPrice(minVal, maxVal) {
    var obj = json['properties'];
    return jQuery.grep(obj, function (item) {
        return item.price < maxVal;
    });
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/dF2W8/

Comment: Thank you for your answer very helpful, how would i return item.price if its item.price > maxVal && item.price > minVal ?

Comment: Like this: return (item.price >= minVal && item.price <= maxVal); ?